# Error in event handler, Type Error : Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In the extension code, I'm trying to suspend a chrome tab by weiting below code.

chrome.tabs.update(tabID,suspendedUrl);
Or
chrome.tabs.update(tabId,{url: suspendedUrl});

Both way I tried but in console  I can see subjected error.

Instead of above code If I use 
windows.replace.url(suspendedUrl)
With this code extension works for me. But with chrome.tabs.update method throws error as mentioned in subject.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message says `chrome.tabs` is undefined so it sounds like this code is inside a content script. Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs API. You need a [background script or popup script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Yes your correct. That code was inside the contentscript.js file. In the background script ,content.js file is injected and suspending code parts available in contentscript.js file. Now how we can write code to suspend tab any brief idea now how I have to proceed.

Comment: You need to send a message from content script to background script. In other words, you should let the extension call the `chrome.tabs` api in background script context.